# Download binary files with angular 7 - Getting corrupt files

Tags: angular, express, binary, corrupt

I'm trying to implement a simple download functionality using Angular 7 but I'm getting corrupt files.

The files (jpg, pdf, zip files) are hosted on a cloud and I'm getting it using an Express Server and the following code:

```
   var url = getBaseUrl() + '/files/' + filename;
   cloudGet(url, getHeaders(req), function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
      ...
    } else {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');
      res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
      res.setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
      res.end(file, 'binary');
    }
  });
```

The header of the file I'm getting looks okay, so I think this part is working.

In Angular I have the following code:
For the service that gets the file, I tried the following solutions:

```
downloadResource(path: string) {
 return this.httpClient.get(path, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

and I also tried this solution:

```
downloadResource2(path: string): Observable<Blob> {
 return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(path,
  { headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'accept': 'application/octet-stream',
     'content-type': 'application/json'}),
    responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
  });
 }
```

In my component I have the following code:

```
downloadFile(filename: string) {
 const downloadUrl = this.apiUrl + '&' + 'filename=' + filename;

 this.apiService.downloadResource(downloadUrl).subscribe(data => {
  const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
  const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = downloadURL;
  link.download = filename;
  link.click();
 });
}
```

This downloads the files to my download folder, but all the files are corrupt (except .json files). The pdf opens but it's empty.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing the code within express to:

```
var url = getBaseUrl() + '/files/' + filename;
  request({
      method: "GET",
      url: url,
      headers: getHeaders(req)
  }).pipe(res);
```